# Scrapy giving errors when trying to start project

Tags: python, scrapy

Just installed with pip I'm using 2.7 I have uninstalled and reinstalled

this is what it's giving me I don't know if it works besides this since I can't get this to run

```
C:\Users>scrapy startproject tutorial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Anaconda\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from scrapy.spider import Spider
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spider.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\__init__.py", line 10, in <mod
ule>
    from scrapy.http.request import Request
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 10,
in <module>
    from w3lib.url import safe_url_string
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\w3lib\url.py", line 9, in <module>
    from six import moves

ImportError: cannot import name moves
```

I don't know what to do

Comment: How are you running it? Can you include the command line?

Comment: sorry I edited it to include the command line

Comment: Seems there's something wrong with `six` package. Can you `pip install -U six` and see what happens?

Comment: Ok I ran that and it says "Requirement already up-to-date: six in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages Cleaning up..."

Comment: Weird, can you open a python interpreter and just try: `from six import moves` and see if it yields the same error? If it does, try to remove `six` completely: `pip uninstall six`.

Comment: I remember now there may have been something screwy when I installed Anaconda. I uninstalled it and reinstalling it now. I'll do that as soon as it finishes installing

Comment: I believe that was the problem I installed scrapy again and now it's running thank you

Comment: You could add an answer with details about the fix, and mark it as accepted, for people that search for the solution to the same problem. Thank you.